# How to import Matlab table ('cell' structure) to R dataframe while conserving proper structure/order?

Tags: r, list, matlab, dataframe

## Problem

Documentation for `readMat()` function says: "For the MAT v5 format, cell structures are read into R as a list structure."

This creates a problem here for me as I am not able to convert it back to the original table structure from the list object. In the original files I inherited, each row (rather than column) represents answers to different questionnaires (row1 = questionnaire1, row2 = questionnaire2, etc.), but the way `readMat()` creates the list is vertically (by column), so my questionnaire items are basically all messed up.

## Code for desired output

Here's code to reproduce a simplified example for the desired output and original file appearance in the `Matlab` `cell` structure:

```
list1 <- list("2",   "34", "17", NA,  NA,  NA)
list2 <- list("32",  "43", NA,   NA,  NA,  NA)
list3 <- list("C",   "D",  "A",  "F", "G", "I")
list4 <- list("455", NA,   NA,   NA,  NA,  NA)
df <- data.frame()
df <- rbind(df,list1,list2,list3,list4)
colnames(df) <- NULL
rownames(df) <- NULL
df
```

This outputs the following (**DESIRED OUTPUT/ORIGINAL MATLAB STRUCTURE**):

```
1   2   34   17 <NA> <NA> <NA>
2  32   43 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
3   C    D    A    F    G    I
4 455 <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>
```

So I can select by row instead of having a messed up order of observations. Note that I replaced the `NULL` values with `NA` for this example else I had an error while making the data frame.

## Code for undesired output

However, to reproduce the outcome of importing in `R` from `Matlab` with `readMat()` we need hefty code like this:

```
list1 <- list(matrix("2"))
list2 <- list(matrix("32"))
list3 <- list(matrix("C"))
list4 <- list(matrix("455"))
list5 <- list(matrix("34"))
list6 <- list(matrix("43"))
list7 <- list(matrix("D"))
list8 <- NULL
list9 <- list(matrix("17"))
list10 <- NULL
list11 <- list(matrix("A"))
list12 <- NULL
list13 <- NULL
list14 <- NULL
list15 <- list(matrix("F"))
list16 <- NULL
list17 <- NULL
list18 <- NULL
list19 <- list(matrix("G"))
list20 <- NULL
list21 <- NULL
list22 <- NULL
list23 <- list(matrix("I"))
list24 <- NULL
(mylist <- list(list1, list2, list3, list4, list5, 
                list6, list7, list8, list9, list10,
                list11, list12, list13, list14, list15,
                list16, list17, list18, list19, list20,
                list21, list22, list23, list24))
```

Which outputs the following:

```
[[1]]
[[1]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "2" 


[[2]]
[[2]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "32"


[[3]]
[[3]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "C" 


[[4]]
[[4]][[1]]
     [,1] 
[1,] "455"


[[5]]
[[5]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "34"


[[6]]
[[6]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "43"


[[7]]
[[7]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "D" 


[[8]]
NULL

[[9]]
[[9]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "17"


[[10]]
NULL

[[11]]
[[11]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "A" 


[[12]]
NULL

[[13]]
NULL

[[14]]
NULL

[[15]]
[[15]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "F" 


[[16]]
NULL

[[17]]
NULL

[[18]]
NULL

[[19]]
[[19]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "G" 


[[20]]
NULL

[[21]]
NULL

[[22]]
NULL

[[23]]
[[23]][[1]]
     [,1]
[1,] "I" 


[[24]]
NULL
```

So in other threads, most people said to *unlist*, but unlisting my list does not allow me to select questionnaires by row for instance  (especially since `NULL` values are not conserved in the dimensions when unlisting):

```
unlist(mylist)
[1] "2"   "32"  "C"   "455" "34"  "43"  "D"   "17"  "A"   "F"   "G"   "I"
```

You can see it's tidier but the items are not in the right order so it's hard to put them back into a data frame. Some said to transform into a matrix... which does not really resolve the problem:

```
matrix(unlist(mylist))    
     [,1] 
 [1,] "2"  
 [2,] "32" 
 [3,] "C"  
 [4,] "455"
 [5,] "34" 
 [6,] "43" 
 [7,] "D"  
 [8,] "17" 
 [9,] "A"  
[10,] "F"  
[11,] "G"  
[12,] "I"
```

I've tried other solutions from the threads to no avail, e.g.:

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, mylist) # doesn't work
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(mylist),nrow=length(mylist),byrow=TRUE)) # doesn't work
```

Here are some related threads: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38505638/importing-data-from-matlab-to-r-nested-structures-into-dataframes), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243524/how-to-import-a-matlab-table-in-r), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29317925/matlab-cell-array-import-via-r-fails), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27306672/r-help-converting-nested-lists-to-data-frame), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49591135/converting-list-to-dataframe-in-r), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50777607/convert-list-of-list-object-to-dataframe-in-r), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43662457/convert-list-of-vectors-to-data-frame), and [8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26284790/matlab-to-r-import-structure).

## Question

1. Why is it necessary for `readMat()` to import `MAT v5` format cell structures as lists rather than data frames (it would save us so much trouble)?
2. I'm looking for a solution ideally in base `R` to transform the `readMat()` list object to a data frame, that I could automatize assuming I have thousands such files that I'm not going to edit, restructure, or save to a different format individually in Matlab, and assuming the number and location of `NULL` values vary, as well as the length of each row (some questionnaires have more items than others). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know why `MAT v5` needs to import tables to lists, but I unexpectedly found a solution!

The function below will easily extract a specific row from that type of list, where `list` is your list, `row` is the row you want to extract, and `nrow` is the total number of rows (given that you know these details):

```
matlab.row <- function(list,row,nrow) {
  unlist(list[seq(row, length(list), nrow)]) # This will take every nth element starting from desired row
}

matlab.row(mylist,1,4)
"2"  "34" "17"
matlab.row(mylist,2,4)
"32" "43"
matlab.row(mylist,3,4)
"C" "D" "A" "F" "G" "I"
matlab.row(mylist,4,4)
"455"
```

In order to get the full data frame, I had to tweak the function some more, where `list` is your list, `max.len` is the length of the longest row (max number of items), and `nrow` is your total number of rows:

```
matlab.df <- function(list,max.len,nrow) {
  matlab.row <- function(list,row,nrow) { # We reuse the function we just made earlier
    unlist(list[seq(row, length(list), nrow)])
  }
  listA <- vector('list', nrow) # Precreates list
  for (i in 1:nrow) {
    listA[i] <- list(c(matlab.row(list,i,nrow), # Combines output from last function to NAs on next line
                  rep(NA, max.len - length(matlab.row(list,i,nrow))))) # Fills the remaining columns with NAs (very important part!)
  }
  df <- do.call(rbind,listA) # Binds elements together from the list we created as rows
  df # Prints dataframe
}

matlab.df(list = mylist, max.len = 6, nrow = 4)
     [,1]  [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,] "2"   "34" "17" NA   NA   NA  
[2,] "32"  "43" NA   NA   NA   NA  
[3,] "C"   "D"  "A"  "F"  "G"  "I" 
[4,] "455" NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```

I found the solution thanks to a combination of these threads: [1](https://www.edureka.co/community/3900/how-to-extract-every-nth-element-of-a-vector-using-r), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12511648/building-a-list-in-a-loop-in-r-getting-item-names-correct), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196450/create-a-data-frame-of-unequal-lengths), and [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29402528/append-data-frames-together-in-a-for-loop/29419402).